# Storing grep output into variable

Tags: perl, grep

I am trying to store grep output in perl into variable using perl, but not working.

```
my $out = `grep -oP "Name = \K(.*)" $file)`;
```

Comment: Why the semicolon at the end?

Comment: Show us sample input. Is there any warning? Does this works outside of Perl in shell?

Comment: Is `$file` is well declared ? Try `print $file` before this line

Comment: @Dominique That's required in Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ERR**:

- you have an extraneous  parenthesis at the end `)`
- always `use strict; use warnings;` you should have seen the error: `Unrecognized escape \K passed through`

input file:

```
Name = foobar
```

code:

```
perl -Mstrict -we 'print qx(grep -oP "Name = \K(.*)" file)'
Unrecognized escape \K passed through at -e line 1.
```

Finally:

```
$ perl -Mstrict -we 'my $out = qx(grep -oP "Name = \\K(.*)" file); print $out'
#                                                  ^^
foobar
```

or a more Perlish way to do it:

```
perl -nE 'say $& if /Name = \K.*/' file
```